# Порядок вызова с super и extends в console

Tags: javascript, консоль, extend

Есть пример кода, но не понятно почему в консоле именно такой порядок выведения

```
bar foo
bar bar
foo bar
```

Разве при вызове super не должен вызываться первым  console.log('foo', this.id)

```
 class Foo {
   constructor() {
     this.id = 'foo'
     this.print()
   }

   print() {
     console.log('foo', this.id)
   }
 }

 class Bar extends Foo {
   constructor() {
     super()
     this.id = 'bar'
     this.print()
     super.print()
   }

   print() {
     console.log('bar', this.id)
   }
 }

 new Bar()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, первым вызывается `this.print()` в 4 строке. А `this` в этот момент экземпляр класса `Bar`, так что вызывается его метод.

Comment: Думаю у ТС возникнет логичный вопрос: а почему исполняется 4 строка и куда девается 3-я

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в смысле? Никуда не девается. Именно из-за неё в первой строке вывода написано `foo` вторым словом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский такое чувство, что это косяк JS, который стоит исправить

Comment: @МихаилКамахин с чего это? Вполне логичное поведение